# Mysql query to get all columns and its sub contents from other table by its id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables named "tasks" and "comments".

I want to get all tasks from "tasks" table.

"comments" table has 2 columns: description and task_id.

task_id is foreign key from task table.

```
$tasks = DB::table('tasks')
       ->join('comments','tasks.id', '=','comments.task_id')
       ->select('tasks.*','comments.*')
       ->get();
```

This code returns error.

How can I do this?

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* on `comments`.* = ``' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `tasks` inner join `comments` on `tasks`.`id` = `comments`.`task_id` inner join `tasks`.* on `comments`.* = ``)

Comment: This does not return all the tasks which does not have comments.

Comment: can you share the error messsage once again its hard to understand  so paste it and share the url  https://paste.laravel.io/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it works perfetcly. Maybe missing import your DB facade? Or you can "\" add DB

```
$members = \DB::table('members')
        ->join('member_daily_bonuses','members.id', '=','member_daily_bonuses.member_id')
        ->select('members.*','member_daily_bonuses.*')
        ->get();

    dd($members);
```

### EDIT

But if they have same columns you must use `members.id as memberId` etc. Otherwise only, records in a table come.

---

Comment: I can see it works but it does not return all members without daily bonuses.

Comment: You must alias for same fields.

Comment: alias? what do you mean

Comment: not returning all members which does not have daily bonuses.

Comment: Then we can use leftJoin  instead of join.

Comment: if we have multiple daily bonuses per member then what can we do?

Comment: You  can use hasMany realation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships please inspect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192150/discussion-between-guru-and-safak-ciplak).